# What Angular expression to use that updates model on click?

Tags: angularjs

I have a couple of hidden DOM-elements:

```
<label ng-show="input">Namn</label>
```

I would like them to be updated using the `ng-click`-attribute. What expression should I use?

Comment: your question is not clear, do you want to show the label when clicking on another element, or use `ng-click` on the hidden element? What would be the point of the latter one?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- some visible element in the same scope -->    
<div ng-click="input = true">Bla Bla</div>
<!-- OR -->
<div ng-click="input = !input">Bla Bla</div>
```

Comment: That was easy, allthough, the ng-click attribute is on another node (you can't really click a node that's hidden ^^

Comment: @KristofferNolgren you can do the same on the node that is visible. As long as both the nodes are in the same scope this should work.

Comment: With expressions it is possible to do it in the view, but in my opinion it is bad practise. Model manipulation is a classic task for a controller.